# How to open .o file?

Tags: c, file-extension

After compiling a C program, you get a .o file. I know it's a file consisting of '0's and '1's and if formed after successful compilation of a program.
But I want to see what is in the file!

Comment: Please do not dual-tag questions with C and C++ tags — it annoys people.  Since you're asking about the object file from a C program, the C tag is appropriate.

Comment: What do you want to see, and what tools do you have?  You can see the bytes or words with tools such as `od`.  If you want to see the structure, you need a tool that understands object files.  What's in the file is the information necessary to make the object file usable — a list of the symbols defined and referenced and information about fixups that are needed when the code is loaded for execution, etc.  There may also be line number and other debugging information, too.

Comment: Oh okay! I'm very new to this! I'll take care next time! Do you know the answer?

Comment: Actually I want to see all the things that you have listed. And is  OD a program to see .o files?

Comment: `od` is 'octal dump'; it will give you a dump of any file, in a number of output formats.  With `od -c`, you'll see each byte separately, with a conversion to a printing character when that's feasible.  It doesn't understand the structure of object files.  You might look for `objdump`.  The `nm` program gives some information too.  There are disassemblers that might help too.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

you've got a couple of choices here.

Firstly (and easiest) is to use something that decodes the file to show you what it is. objdump on linux does this.

```
gcc -c test.c
```

gives you test.o

```
objdump -D test.o
```

will decode the file and show you what's in it on standard output (so pipe it to less or similar)
Objdump output shows you the unlinked object file. The addresses aren't valid and have to be fixed up by the linker.
the format is 
first a line number
then some number of bytes that are the cpu instruction, these are shown in hexadecimal.eg 14 means 00010100
next comes the instruction that these byes represent

```
   0:   14 00                   adc    $0x0,%al
```

so above we have line 0 of the function - it's unlinked)
14 00 - these are the bytes
they mean add with carry 0 to the al register storing the result in al

Another alternative is to use a hex editor and try and work out what 14 00 means without any assistance.

Good luck.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `hexdump` command from the terminal to display the content.

**Syntax :** `$ hexdump <filename>.o`

It will show you the content in `hexadecimal` form.

Comment: Error: 'hexdump' is not recognized as an internal or external command. Doesn't seem to work in Windows cmd nor git bash. What are the prerequisites for hexdump?

Comment: hexdump is a linux command, but not clue about a windows alternative.